# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php

Why would I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

when I use this in a prepared PDO statment.

```
            $stmt->execute(
            ':name' => $nme,
            ':street' => $strt,
            ':suburb' => $sbrb,
            ':city' => $cty,
            ':province' => $cnty,
            ':country' => $cntry
        );
```

It was dont on the example of

```
$id = 5;
$name = "Joe the Plumber";

try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDatabase', $username, $password);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE someTable SET name = :name WHERE id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':id'   => $id,
    ':name' => $name
  ));

  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You need to pass an array to execute

Comment: Basically, you forgot the `array( ... )` part ;)

Comment: okay... that was embarrising.. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to (note the array):

```
$stmt->execute(array(
        ':name' => $nme,
        ':street' => $strt,
        ':suburb' => $sbrb,
        ':city' => $cty,
        ':province' => $cnty,
        ':country' => $cntry
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be a little more accurate with you code:

```
$stmt->execute( **array(**
            ':name' => $nme,
            ':street' => $strt,
            ':suburb' => $sbrb,
            ':city' => $cty,
            ':province' => $cnty,
            ':country' => $cntry
        **)**);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass an array, so change your code to:

```
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':name' => $nme,
        ':street' => $strt,
        ':suburb' => $sbrb,
        ':city' => $cty,
        ':province' => $cnty,
        ':country' => $cntry
    ));
```